# Printing map from google maps without controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using the google map api v2.  When I go to print the map, the controls are being displayed on the print out.  How can I set GLargeMapControl and GMapTypeControl not to print?

I seen in the API there is a GControl Printable constuctor but can not find any information on its usage.

I have tried using these 2 functions:

> function Clickheretoprint()
>            {
>             var disp_setting="toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,";
>         disp_setting+="scrollbars=no,width=650,
>   height=600, left=100, top=25";
>         var content_vlue = document.getElementById("gm").innerHTML;
>
> ```
> var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting);
>
> docprint.document.open();
> docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Inel
> ```
>
> Power System');
>
> ```
> docprint.document.write('</head><body
> ```
>
> class="gmnoprint print"
>   onLoad="window.print();window.close()">');
>       docprint.document.write(content_vlue);
>       docprint.document.write('');
>       docprint.document.close();
>       docprint.focus();    }

and

> function ClickHereToPrint(){  try {
>
> ```
>   var oIframe =
> ```
>
> document.getElementById('ifrmPrint');
>         var oContent =
>   document.getElementById('gm').innerHTML;
>         var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow ||
>   oIframe.contentDocument);         if
>   (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
>         oDoc.write("title");
>         oDoc.write("");
>         oDoc.write(oContent + "");
>         oDoc.close();   }
>
> catch(e){
>
> ```
>   self.print();
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

In the HTML page I have:

> var lat, lon, init_zoom;
>       lat = 44.9647979303;
>       lon = -99.84375; 
>       init_zoom = 3;
>       
>       Google Maps Print test
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="mapscripts.js"></script> </head>
> ```
>
> Print
>
> ```
>             <div id="bottomDiv" class="clsBottomDiv" align="left">
>                 <table>
>                     <tr>
>                         <td>
>                             Search for Address:
>                           <form onSubmit="return Geocode()">
>                             <input id="search" type="text" size="60"
> ```
>
> />
>
> ```
>                     </tr>
>                 </table>
>             </div>
>
>         </td>
>     </tr>
> </table> </div> </body> </html>
> ```

I tried giving the iframe a class of gmnoprint also with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a print stylesheet :)

[You can read all about it here](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml)

Google already made it easy for you, just target the class 'gmnoprint' and you can get rid of all that stuff :)

If you don't want an extra print stylesheet you can just add this rule to your existing stylesheet:

```
@media print {
   .gmnoprint {display: none;}
}
```

or inline it in your page:

```
<style>
@media print {
   .gmnoprint {display: none;}
}
</style>
```

Comment: your testpage works fine for me, and doesn't print the overlays - what browser are you using?

Comment: When I print the page from the browsers menu bar it prints fine.. but when I try via javascript (clickign the word "Print" on the page) it doesn't..

Comment: That should tell you that the problem is your javascript print implementation, and not the print stylesheet :)